# Change file arrangement in windows explorer

Tags: c#, windows, explorer

I am looking for a way to obtain and change information regarding the files arrangement in windows explorer so that I can automatically set that in certain folder will be set Group by => Type (file type) which is needed for application I am working on.

Comment: Does it have to be in Windows Explorer? If you only need to display files/folders within your own application then you can use the ListView control and populate it however you like, or something like that

Comment: It has to be in Windows Explorer because the whole point of this application will be to change bit the arrangement of files in certain areas/folders the user sets and for that I need to have a control over the Explorer's group by arrangement.

Comment: Apparently Windows uses something called "shellbags" to keep track of these settings in the registry. Maybe these will be good places to start looking?
http://www.williballenthin.com/forensics/shellbags/
http://superuser.com/questions/576598/remember-each-folders-view-settings-in-windows-7

Comment: Thank you Matt I will have a look at it straight away.

Comment: Hopefully that helps. Be sure to come back here and post the answer if/when you find it. I'm sure someone else might wonder the same thing in the future, because it sounds kind of useful to be able to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573501/group-by-a-certain-folder-in-windows-explorer/29577252

Comment: @DenisAnisimov would you be able to convert your delphi code to C# as I am not familiar with Deplhi at all? I would test your code on both win7 and other systems and post the result of it.

Comment: Sorry but I am not C# developer.