# Getting the sorting order of a folder as defined in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

I am attempting to recreate Windows Photo Viewer with Python. The photo viewer has a feature where the images are displayed in the same order as how it appears in Windows Explorer. For instance, if I opened an image in a folder which is sorted by date in Explorer, then pressing "previous image" and "next image" in Windows Photo Viewer would go through the image files in order of date. If the folder was sorted by size in Explorer, then Windows Photo Viewer would go through the images in order of size.

[Here is what I mean by a folder's sorting method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ6bd.png) You can sort a folder in explorer by clicking the header of any column. It seems every folder can have its own sorting method, by name, date, type, size etc.

Is there any way to obtain the sorting order of a particular folder as in Windows Explorer?

Comment: This is given by the IFolderView2::GetSortColumns method method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifolderview2-getsortcolumns not sure how you get that from your python code. What winapi object do you have ahold on?

Comment: There's the [pywin32 library](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32_modules.html). But IFolderView2 doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: Here is an example that shows how to get started with pyton: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43968304/403671 IFolderView2 can be retrieved from IShellView (for most folders)

Comment: Actually, is there any other method that doesn't require looking through Explorer instances? I'm thinking maybe accessing where explorer stores its settings might be more direct and better

Comment: MS has a standard [IFolderView2 interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifolderview2) for us to query some information about the explorer. Not sure why you reject the method.

Comment: I'm thinking of cases where I don't launch the program through opening an image in explorer. So for example I launch the program executable directly, then open an image file with the program's open dialog. There wouldn't be an explorer instance looking at the image file's directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Group by" a certain folder in windows explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573501/group-by-a-certain-folder-in-windows-explorer)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365499/how-to-get-a-complete-explorer-listing-related-to-a-file-used-to-launch-an-assoc