# How to get windows folder display order by C + +

Tags: windows, qt, c++11, winapi, directory

I need to get the pictures in the windows folder and sort them according to the order in which they are displayed. Now there is a method to traverse the entire folder display items through the handle by getting the folder window handle. However, this method has a drawback: it can't get the order of the unopened folder, because there is no open file and no window handle.
Qt is used.
Please forgive my grammatical mistakes.

```
//Find out the current folder window according to the mouse click position
HWND findOpenFileWindow(const QString& path)
{
    Sleep(3 * 1000);
    POINT pNow = { 0, 0 };
    if (!GetCursorPos(&pNow))
        return NULL;

    TCHAR  szClass[255] = {0};
    HWND pMouseChooseHandle = WindowFromPoint(pNow);
    HWND pParent = ::GetParent(pMouseChooseHandle);

    GetClassName(pParent, szClass, 255);
    if (_tcscmp(szClass, L"SHELLDLL_DefView") == 0 || _tcscmp(szClass, L"NSEViewClass") == 0 )
    {
        bool bQingDisk = _tcscmp(szClass, L"NSEViewClass") == 0;
        pParent = ::GetParent(pParent);
        GetClassName(pParent, szClass, 255);
        if (_tcscmp(szClass, L"WorkerW"))
        {
            pParent = pMouseChooseHandle;
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                if(pParent != NULL)
                    pParent = ::GetParent(pParent);
            }
            HWND pChild = ::GetWindow(pParent, GW_CHILD);
            GetClassName(pChild, szClass, 255);
            while (pChild != NULL)
            {
                GetClassName(pChild, szClass, 255);
                if (_tcscmp(szClass, TEXT("ShellTabWindowClass")) == 0)
                {
                    pParent = pChild;
                    break;
                }
                pChild = ::GetNextWindow(pChild, GW_HWNDNEXT);
            }
            TCHAR  exploreWndName[MAX_PATH] = {0};
            ::GetWindowText(pParent, exploreWndName, MAX_PATH);
            if(QFileInfo(path).fileName() == QString().fromWCharArray(exploreWndName))
                return pParent;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

//Traverse window display items, get them
QStringList listNormalFolderFile( const QString& path, const QStringList& filter )
{
    HWND folderWnd = findOpenFileWindow(path);

    HWND          hwnd;
    IDispatch     *pDispatch;
    CComPtr<IShellWindows> pShellWindows;

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellWindows, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellWindows));
    if (FAILED(hr)) 
    {
        CoUninitialize();
        return QStringList();
    }
    LONG lCount = 0;
    pShellWindows->get_Count(&lCount);

    QStringList fileList;
    for (LONG i = 0; i < lCount; i++) 
    {
        CComPtr<IShellBrowser> pShellBrowser;
        VARIANT  var;
        var.vt = VT_I4;
        var.lVal = i;
        if(SUCCEEDED(pShellWindows->Item(var, &pDispatch))) 
        {
            if(SUCCEEDED(IUnknown_QueryService(pDispatch, SID_STopLevelBrowser, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pShellBrowser))))
            {
                if (SUCCEEDED(IUnknown_GetWindow(pShellBrowser, &hwnd)))
                {
                    TCHAR  szBuf[256];
                    GetWindowText(hwnd, szBuf, sizeof(szBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR));
                    if(QFileInfo(path).fileName() != QString().fromWCharArray(szBuf))
                        continue;

                    CComPtr<IShellView> pShellView;
                    if(FAILED(pShellBrowser->QueryActiveShellView(&pShellView)))
                        continue;

                    CComPtr<IFolderView> pFv = NULL;
                    /*
                    do something here
                    */

                    CComPtr<IPersistFolder2 > pFolder;
                    if( FAILED(pFv->GetFolder(IID_IPersistFolder2, (void**) &pFolder)))
                        continue;

                    LPITEMIDLIST pidl = nullptr;
                    if( SUCCEEDED(pFolder->GetCurFolder(&pidl)))
                    {
                        wchar_t cPath[32767];
                        if( ::SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, cPath))
                        {
                            QString filePath;
                            QFileInfo fileInfo(filePath.fromWCharArray(cPath));
                            if(fileInfo.absoluteFilePath() == QFileInfo(path).absoluteFilePath())
                            {
                                if(folderWnd == NULL || folderWnd == hwnd)
                                {
                                    fileList = listFileInBrowser(pShellBrowser, filter);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return fileList;
```

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573501/group-by-a-certain-folder-in-windows-explorer

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand correctly, you want to enumerate all picture files (recursive subfolders) under the path, and you also need to enumerate in order, right? Then I recommend using `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile`, but this is not in order, you need to enumerate all files in current folder, sort them manually, and then go into the child folder recursively.

Comment: Thank you very much. But this is not what I want. I want to get the order of the files displayed when Windows Explorer is opened, rather than just get them and sort them myself.

Comment: How do you implement the `listFileInBrowser` function? Have you tried using `SHParseDisplayName` to convert the absolute path into a `PIDL`, and then `SHBindToParent` that gives you the `IShellFolder` pointer, and then you could call the `EnumObjects` method?

Comment: thank! But this is also not what I want. I hope that the order of the traversed files and folders is the same as the order displayed by Windows Explorer. Your suggestion can get the contents of the folders but the default is to sort by name.[I use Microsoft official website source code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/navigate),Thanks again, You gave me a direction to work hard.

Comment: Even in the sample you sent, it is not enumerated in the order of displaying. But you can [Determining how each Explorer window is sorted](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151228-00/?p=92721). AFAIK, there is no way to get the display order of unopened shellwindow, they are not even displayed yet. As an alternative, you can use `ShellExecute` to temporarily start a file explorer with `nShowCmd = SW_HIDE`, and then destroy the window after traversing.

Comment: thanks a lot! I chose another way. just sort by myself. And I tried your method, `ShellExecute ` opens folders which sort by name default.

Comment: @Ryan Glad you solved the problem, you could post your own answer and accept yourself.